# FlutterWeb app build problem with REST - how to make backend to communicate with my API

Tags: flutter, dart, build, production

I have a problem. I've created a Flutter web application that includes REST queries to my API. Only after building it, I realized that it won't work in production due to CORS policy. Is there a way to create a shelf server so that my web application and that server can communicate internally without opening a new port for that server?

I cant find any example of that in flutter documentation.

Comment: You can use IIS(Internet Information Services), that u can publish your API in local server.

Comment: Where do you plan to run this shelf server? In the cloud somewhere? Then, sure. You obviously cannot run shelf inside the browser!